# Windows 10 - Some parts of the UI not working after the latest cumulative update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1903

I'm running Windows 10 build 18362.295. Last day i checked for updates and installed the available cumulative update including the OS security updates. After the installation of these updates i started facing the below issues which happens often (sometime everything is working properly)

- Some parts of the GUI (on every window) is not working
- I'm not able to use my touchpad gesture controls
- Not able to click task bar icons, start button or anything on my task bar
- It automatically triggers right click

I tried these methods to solve the issue:

- Tried uninstalling the latest cumulative updates, visiting `Installed updates`. But it is not showing uninstall option. I also tried the command line method but that too didn't work.
- I ran these commands and restarted my PC,

```
sfc /scannow
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
```

As per `View update history` i have,

```
2019-08 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1903 for x64-based Systems (KB4512941) (2)
```

As per `Installed Updates`

```
 Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4512508)
```

I'm able to do all UI interaction using only keyboard, but not able to do the same using my external mouse or touch pad. As already mentioned these issues started after the recent updates. I tried searching google, but no where i found any useful information or problem similar to this.

**Update**

As pointed out by [@john](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john), i was not on the latest build. So i checked for updates again and installed updates.

Now the *View Update History* window shows this,

```
2019-08 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1903 for x64-based Systems (KB4512941) 

2019-08 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1903 for x64-based Systems (KB4512941) (2)
```

And *Installed Updates* window shows this,

```
Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4512941)
```

I'm now on the latest build 18362.329

Comment: Checking for updates is a trap, as it forces the installation of updates untested for your computer. Try to rollback to a previous System Restore point (if you have one).

Comment: The current build is now .329. Try updating to the newest build and see if that solves the issue. Since you have run SFC and DISM and that did not solve the problem, try a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything.  Use the Microsoft Media Creation link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: @harrymc I don't have a restore point.

Comment: @John I'm now on the latest build.

Comment: Please try using the Repair Install as noted earlier

Comment: @John I tried but didn't work. The issue is still present.

Comment: If you did all the things above without result (as you said), then at this point, you probably should back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @John It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@John](https://superuser.com/questions/1480173/windows-10-some-parts-of-the-ui-not-working-after-the-latest-cumulative-update?noredirect=1#comment2231286_1480173) commented.

I downloaded Windows 10 to USB using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and [Windows Updates Show/Hide Tool](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab).

Then, i just run the `setup.exe` file with *Airplane Mode* turned *ON*. I don't know why but it prompted me to install the upgrade (I had checked my ***About Your PC*** it was showing Build *18362.239*)

After the upgrade, i ran the ***wushowhide.diagcab*** which allowed me to ***hide*** windows updates.

Everything works fine now.